# Identify an assembly's target runtime using NDepend

Tags: ndepend, static-code-analysis

Can someone help me to write a CQL query for NDepend 3.8 to get all assemblies that are built against a specific Dot .NET runtime (i.e. 4.0.x vs 2.0.x)

Thanks!

Comment: This is not something that can be achieved through NDepend v3 nor v4